# Exclusive access to function using PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, curl

I'm trying to call GetAllDomains in a codeigniter library, but when 2 calls happens simultaneously this method throw errors, any solution to call it exclusively or using mutex, the first user call this method and the others wait until release.
the code that call GetAllDomains:

```
public function index(){

    $this->data['menu'] = 1;
    $this->data['message'] = $this->session->flashdata('message');

    $domains = $this->exchange_api->GetAllDomains();

    if(is_null($domains)){ 
        $domains = array();
    }

    var_dump($domains);

}
```

GetAllDomains function:

```
public function GetAllDomains(){
    $domains = $this->ci->rest->post('GetAllDomain');
    return isset($domains->Result) && $domains->Result == 1 ? $domains->Param: null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use [flock](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.flock.php)

```
$fp = fopen("/tmp/lock.txt", "w+");
if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) { // lock
    sleep(10); // your function execute
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN); // unlock
} else {
    echo "failed";
}
fclose($fp);
```

Or mysql [getLock](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock) with similar algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Thanx that was useful

```
public function GetAllDomains(){

    $this->ci->mutex->Lock();
    $domains = $this->ci->rest->post('GetAllDomain');
    $this->ci->mutex->Release();

    return isset($domains->Result) && $domains->Result == 1 ? $domains->Param: null;
}
```

Mutex Class:

```
public function Lock(){

    $this->fp = fopen($this->lockFilePath, "w+");
    flock($this->fp, LOCK_EX);

}

public function Release(){

    flock($this->fp, LOCK_UN);
    fclose($this->fp);

}
```